# How do I create a "chained" schematic?

Tags: angular, angular-schematics

I don't know the correct term for what I need, so I will try to explain it as clear as possible.

In CLIs like `sequelize-cli` you can run either `sequelize db:create` or `sequelize db:drop`. I want to create two schematics whose first part is a command in itself, but if you add a second part it will execute a different schematic.

Specifically, I want to :

- Run `mySchematic:migration` and create a lot of files.
- Run `mySchematic:migration:express` and it will only create migrations for express.
- Run `mySchematic:migration:hapi` and it will only create migrations for hapi.

I know how to achieve the functionality, but I am not able to get it to execute the different commands. When I run `mySchematic:migration:hapi`, the schematic that is executed is always `mySchematic:migration`.

This is my `collection.json`:

```
{
  "$schema": "../node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/collection-schema.json",
  "schematics": {
    "migration": {
      "description": "description.",
      "factory": "./migrations/index#migration",
      "schema": "./migrations/migration-schema.json"
    },
    "migration:express": {
      "description": "description.",
      "factory": "./migrations/index#express",
      "schema": "./migrations/express-schema.json"
    },
  },
  "migration:hapi": {
    "description": "description.",
    "factory": "./migrations/index#hapi",
    "schema": "./migrations/hapi-schema.json"
  },
}
```

Changing the order of the schematics does not work either.

I have also tried this, but it didn't work either:

```
{
  "$schema": "../node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/collection-schema.json",
  "schematics": {
    "migration": {
      "description": "description.",
      "factory": "./migrations/index#migration",
      "schema": "./migrations/migration-schema.json",
      "express": {
        "description": "description.",
        "factory": "./migrations/index#express",
        "schema": "./migrations/express-schema.json"
      },
      "hapi": {
        "description": "description.",
        "factory": "./migrations/index#hapi",
        "schema": "./migrations/hapi-schema.json"
      }
    }
  }
}
```